# How to name wildcard select columns in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, left-join, wildcard

I will simplify my scenario - I have these 2 tables:

```
table_A - id int, id_table_B_one int, id_table_B_two int, name varchar(30)
table_B - id int, name varchar(30), description varchar(30)
```

Then I have this query:

```
SELECT
table_A.id, table_A.name, table_B_one.*, table_B_two.* 
FROM
table_A
LEFT JOIN table_B table_B_one ON table_A.id_table_B_one = table_B.id
LEFT JOIN table_B table_B_two ON table_A.id_table_B_two = table_B.id
```

My problem is that I will get 3 columns with the same names (id and name). I know I can use 'AS' keyword to specify one column's alias. However, I would need to specify each selected column, but I have to use '*' wildcard.

Is there any way how can set alias column name with '*' wildcard ? Something like this:

... table_B_one.* AS table_B_one_* ...

Comment: why do you need to use wildcards?  can't you just spell out all of the columns you want to see?

Comment: Instead of `*` or `table.*`, best to be explicit about the columns you are selecting anyway. List them all in the `SELECT` statement.

Comment: TokenMacGuy: I need to, because the SQL query is actually dynamically generated. As I stated in my question - it is very simplified for purpose of this question but query and its usage in my case is much more complex

Comment: There seems no way to do this (found several feature requests on mysql tracker declined) though you can create view that would remap your column names (add prefixes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't a way set aliases using a wildcard. You need to be explicit.

If your SQL is dynamically generated, then the cost (to you) of being explicit with all the necessary aliases is extremely small - just put the generation of the correct aliases into the code that generates the SQL.

Being explicit with the aliases will help the readability of the code - which is what aliases are there for. However, I'm curious: why do you want aliases if your SQL is dynamically generated?

Comment: They probably want to create a Eloquent like relationship system. Aliases will help determine from which table the field is from thus to which object it's going to be assigned.